# How do I fix this grainy background?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to add a nice, dark backdrop to my renders:

[image: Grainy background]

This backdrop is a simple plane, which I extruded into an L shape and then curved the seam.  I'm rendering the images for this gif in Eevee, and while the figure and the sign behind it look right to me, the background is really grainy and, I think, very ugly.

I've tried increasing the Render samples from 64 to 400, but it seemed to get worse.  How do I fix this grainy background?

Comment: Are you talking about the bands and the noisy borders between two regions of different value(Color value)?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.  You're talking about the grey area, right?

Comment: those are most probably compression artifacts. If that's not the case try the denoise node in the compositor.

Comment: I reduced compression from 15% to 0%.  It tripled the file size of each image, but there was no improvement.  If it's a denoising issue, does Blender have a denoise option with the Eevee renderer?

Comment: It looks like a color-depth problem - banding like that is common with 8 bit depth - try increasing to 16 bit. (Can be found in the output properties tab, where you choose your output type).

Comment: What file format do you output into?

Comment: @L0Lock I use PNG.  And Christopher Bennett, I increased it to 16 bit.  No change.

Comment: Do you see this banding effect in the PNG file or only after converting into a GIF?

Comment: I was just coming here to add that info.  The individual images look fine; it's only when converting to GIF that the banding happens.  Hmm...maybe not a Blender issue, then.

Comment: Yes, it's a color depth conversion that happens when saving as GIF.  Recommend playing around with ScreenToGif to get an idea for file sizes and the trade-offs.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about gif compression. Not blender.

Comment: Blender is generating the images that make up this gif.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the problem by converting the PNGs to an animated PNG (APNG).  The distortions disappeared when I did that.

The GIF image format has an upper limit of 256 colors and this was what appeared to be producing the banding artifacts.